# Array keeps repeating horizontally

Tags: php, sql

I've got 27 areas where people were counted once per hour for 10 hours. My array keeps repeating the same counts for all areas in each row when I need it to output the counts specific to that area # then move to the next row and so on. Not sure if it's my SQL query or my php loop or both.

[array repeating image http://slographicarts.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/arrays_repeating.jpg](http://slographicarts.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/arrays_repeating.jpg)

```
    <?php 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="tableTdContent">Areas</td>';
    echo '<td class="tableTdContent">Area ID</td>';
    foreach($rhh as $hr)
    { 
    echo '<td class="tableTdContent">'. ($hr['fac_reports']['hour']).'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    $j=0;
    foreach($raa as $all)
{ 
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td class="tableTdContent">'. strip_tags($all['fac_reports']['areaname']).'</td>';
echo '<td class="tableTdContent">' . $j . '</td>';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($hr); $i++)
{
foreach ($coo as $count)
    {
    echo '<td class="tableTdContent">'.$count['fac_reports']['count'].'</td>'; 
    }

}
echo '</tr>';
$j++}

?>
```

[sql and array http://slographicarts.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/array_sql.jpg](http://slographicarts.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/array_sql.jpg)

Comment: What is `$hr`? What is `$coo`? Why are there *three* loops for a two dimensional table? Why are you using `$all` in your outer *and* inner loop? What does your array look like to begin with? I think you should start by trying to debug this mess yourself.

Comment: That image is messing with my eyes

Comment: I think this will be a lot easier for you to debug if you break down the loops into their own methods and use more descriptive variable names. Just from looking at this script it is very hard to determine what the intent of the function is. From what I can gather I think it will help to first flatten the results from your SQL query into a simple 2 dimension array, then loop through that to create your html.

Comment: This might even be easier to just start again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's still not enough information to go on, but I'm very positive your problem is the double inner loop:

```
foreach (...) {
    for (...) {
        foreach (...) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

You only need one of those inner loops.

---

OK then, your main problem is that your array format is pretty hard to loop through. Here's a way to reformat the array into something that you can easily loop through and the complete table output:

```
<?php

$groupedByArea = array();
foreach ($coo as $row) {
    extract($row['fac_reports']);
    $groupedByArea[$area][$hour] = $count;
}

?>
<table>
    <!-- table headers -->
    <tr>
        <th>Area</th>
        <?php foreach (array_keys(current($groupedByArea)) as $hour) : ?>
            <th><?php echo $hour; ?></th>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>

    <!-- data rows -->
    <?php foreach ($groupedByArea as $area => $counts) : ?>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $area; ?></th>
            <?php foreach ($counts as $count) : ?>
                <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

(Untested, but I hope you get the idea.)
This does depend on the hours being sorted identically in all retrieved rows, otherwise the output will not match up with the actual data.

Comment: when I remove the inner loop (the foreach $coo as $count) and simply change $count['fac_reports']['count'] back to $all['fac_reports']['count'] it repeats downward 270 times. So I have 10 rows of each area instead of 1 row. Believe me I've tried many possibilities which is why I've posted it. Thanks for your willingness to assist.

Comment: that's awesome! Thanks. Now I just need to get the hours to output am to pm.